# How to specify which parent class to use in super( ) function in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding

My Objective: Create the method named [identify2] in child class that invokes the [identify] method from Parent2 class. This must be done using super() keyword.

My problem: the method names in both parent class are the same. But I want to pertain only to the method of parent2 class using super() keyword. what should I do?

```
class Parent1:
  def identify(self):
    return "This method is called from Parent1"
    
class Parent2:
  def identify(self):
    return "This method is called from Parent2"
    
# declare child class here
class child(Parent1, Parent2):
  def identify(self):
    return "This method is called from Child"
  def identify2(self):
    super().identify()  # I want to call the method of Parent2 class, how?     
  
  
child_object = child()
#                                           Expected output:
print( child_object.identify() )        # This method is called from Child
print( child_object.identify2() )       # This method is called from Parent2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` can be called with type and object parameters, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). The type parameter determines after which class in the mro order the search for the method will start. In this case, to get a method of `Parent2` the search should start after `Parent1`:

```
class Parent1:
    def identify(self):
        return "This method is called from Parent1"
    
class Parent2:
    def identify(self):
        return "This method is called from Parent2"
    
# declare child class here
class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def identify(self):
        return "This method is called from Child"
    
    def identify2(self):
        return super(Parent1, self).identify()
  
  
child_object = Child()
#                                           Expected output:
print( child_object.identify() )        # This method is called from Child
print( child_object.identify2() )       # This method is called from Parent2
```

This gives:

```
This method is called from Child
This method is called from Parent2
```